# How to model repeating pyramid pattern shrinking in the center?

Tags: geometry

An object was created that repeats, narrows towards the center. There is an animation.

I'm graduating please help

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

I found this model on youtube
This model is based on the "Golden Ratio"
[Click to video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3A22G.jpg)

Comment: What's up with graduating? How can we help with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a plane, subdivide, select its middle face, activate the *Proportional Editing* option, scale down, rotate on Z. Create a pyramid:

[image]

Enable the addon called [Tissue](https://github.com/alessandro-zomparelli/tissue) (by alessandro-zomparelli), open the *N panel > Tissue*, select the pyramid, shift select the plane, click on the *Tesselate* button then *OK*:

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH ! <3